# woocoomerce product page shortcode for specific variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to add a product page shortcode ([product_page id="99"]) for a specific variation as example: [product_page id="99" variation_name="VALUE"]?

Comment: By default, no.
You can however use the SKU or product ID of the variation, which will be different than the base product ID.

Comment: but if I use the var.-ID for the page_product shortcode, they show up only the Product Page without the variation